# Duplicacion de notificaciones Webhook MercadoLibre

Tags: mercadolibre

Estoy enfrentando un problema inusual con los webhooks de MercadoLibre en mi aplicación y me preguntaba si alguien podría ayudarme a encontrar una solución o darme alguna orientación. Aquí está el problema:

Descripción del Problema:

Recibo webhooks de MercadoLibre para mi aplicación, y estoy respondiendo a estos webhooks con un código de estado 200 OK para confirmar la recepción. Sin embargo, he notado que en algunos casos, los webhooks se duplican, lo que no debería ocurrir.

Detalles Adicionales:

He implementado una respuesta 200 OK de manera inmediata al recibir el webhook para cumplir con las recomendaciones de la documentación de MercadoLibre.

El tiempo de respuesta de mi aplicación es bastante rápido (alrededor de 2.368 ms), por lo que no parece ser la causa del problema.

Tengo dudas que puede ser al utilizar NGROK como túnel para desviar el webhook a mi localhost el motivo de que Meli me siga enviando notificaciones constantemente.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.